# What is better to use to communicate with a child component - $emit or $ref?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Tell me, please.
There is a page for changing user data. This page consists of fields for entering information about the user and a Submit button.
I need to create a popup component that performs the same functions.
The form itself will now be in a child component. The submit button is now moved to the parent component.
Therefore, I need to pass the entered data to the parent component. Everything is complicated by the fact that initially data comes from the server with previously entered information about the user. Therefore, initially you need to transfer data to the child component through props, and then, when changing them from the child, transfer it to the parent.
But what if there are a lot of variables?
For example: I need to create 15 props and then pass this data through $emit. The data itself is passed either through the @input event of the <input> tag or the @change event of the <select> tag.
I thought of three options, but I don't know which one is better. Or maybe some should not be used at all.

1. **Using $emit**

Parent component

```
<template>
  <Child 
    :first-props="user.first"
    :second-props="user.second"
    ....
    :fifteenth-props="user.fifteenth"
  />
  <button @click='submit'>Submit</button>
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/Child.vue'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    first: '',
    second: '',
    ...
    fifteenth: ''
  }),
  components: {
    Child
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      user: 'user/getUser'
    })
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
     //Sending data
    }
  },
  mounted: {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/getUserData')
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="first" @input="username" />
    <input type="text" value="second" @input="name" />
    <input type="text" value="fifteenth" @input="surname" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    first: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    first: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    ...
    fifteenth: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    username() {
     this.$emit('changeUsername', first)
    },
    name() {
     this.$emit('changeName', second)
    },
    surname() {
     this.$emit('changeSurname', fifteenth)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this variant, I am worried about the number of props. I do not know if this can somehow affect the speed and quality of the component.

2. **Using $ref**

Parent component

```
<template>
  <Child 
    ref='childComponent'
  />
  <button click="submit">Submit</button>
</template>

<script>
import Child from '@/components/Child.vue'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    first: '',
    second: '',
    ...
    fifteenth: ''
  }),
  components: {
    Child
  },
  method: {
    submit() {
      this.$refs.childComponent.submit()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="first" @input="username" />
    <input type="text" v-model="second" @input="name" />
    <input type="text" v-model="fifteenth" @input="surname" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    first: '',
    second: '',
    ...
    fifteenth: ''
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      user: 'user/getUser'
    })
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
     //Sending data
    }
  },
  mounted: {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/getUserData')
  }
}
</script>
```

In this variant, there is not much interaction between the parent and child component. And the parent component fires only the submit method. Plus, you don't need to change the existing code too much, as you just need to move the button. But here I am concerned: is it not a bad decision to apply ref in this way ? And the second problem is the availability of data when the button is clicked. It is more likely that the child component has not yet received the necessary data or simply has not loaded yet, and the user has already pressed the button.
For example, the parent component already has a main title and a submit button. But the child component is still loading.
Although the solution here can be to make the button available for pressing only after loading the child component using :disabled="isDisabled".

3. **Using vuex**

This option immediately seems wrong to me, since the data will be used only inside this component. And vuex seems to me suitable only for global cases.

I have tried all three options and they all work. But I wanted the code not only to work, but also to be correct.

Comment: @EstusFlask
Thanks for the answer.
I changed the title a bit. I hope this better shows what the question is.
As for option 1: thanks, I didn’t think to combine everything into one big Props. For example, in one big object.

Comment: @Estus Flask And about the 2nd option: the problem is in the methods of sending data. If you transfer the button to the parent component, then you will have to transfer the methods for sending data there as well. But there may be several of them. Then, as a result, you will have to go to the first option, since all methods will need variables from the child component. In the second option, I just wanted not to transfer the functionality from the child component, but to refer to it through the ref.

Comment: I misread 2, it can be handled a tad differently in this case, moved the explanation to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ref` and `$emit` don't serve the same purpose, there's generally no choice between them.

Option 1 can use a single data prop in a child:

```
<input
  type="text"
  :value="formData.first"
  @input="$emit('updateFormData', { key: 'first', value: $event.target.value }))"
/>
```

And merge the changes in a parent:

```
  <Child 
    :formData="formData"
    @updateFormData="formData[$event.key] = $event.value"
  />
```

Option 2 is possible in its current state. Alternatively, a child can be made self-contained and contain submit button, then there is no use for `$ref`. It can emit `submit` event in case there's business logic associated with form submit that shouldn't be moved to a child.

Option 3 is possible but the use of global store for local purposes is not justified, local stores can be achieved with Vuex dynamic modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the first option. It turns out very short and excellent.
As for the variant with vuex, I thought so. That it is too global for such a small task.

Comment: About the second option. Ideally, I would like to have two additional child components for the separation inside the main component. One with form fields and data submission methods. The second with one or more buttons as needed. From the second one, make $emit to the parent one and there, through the ref, run the submit() method inside the first child component. So that the parent component does not contain a lot of code and is only a binder. But is it possible to do this or is it condemned?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and there's nothing terribly wrong with it, although I don't remember doing this kind of separation. I wouldn't move submit button outside Child without a good reason. If the form needs customizable buttons, a child can use a slot for them.

Comment: Exactly, I can use the slot. Thanks again. The first option or slot is what I need. Now I will experiment what works best in my case.